# When using CoTaskMemAlloc, should I always call CoTaskMemFree?

Tags: memory-management, com, atl

I'm writing some COM and ATL code, and for some reason all the code uses `CoTaskMemAlloc` to allocate memory instead of `new` or `malloc`. So I followed along this coding style and I also use `CoTaskMemAlloc`.

My teachers taught me to always `delete` or `free` when allocating memory. However I'm not sure if I should always be calling `CoTaskMemFree` if I use `CoTaskMemAlloc`?

Comment: Related reading: [Allocating and freeing memory across module boundaries](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/15/755966.aspx).

Answer (score 10):

Using the CRT's provided new/malloc and delete/free is a problem in COM interop.  To make them work, it is *very* important that the same copy of the CRT both allocates and releases the memory.  That's impossible to enforce in a COM interop scenario, your COM server and the client are practically guaranteed to use different versions of the CRT.  Each using their own heap to allocate from.  This causes undiagnosable memory leaks on Windows XP, a hard exception on Vista and up.

Which is why the COM heap exists, a single predefined heap in a process that's used both by the server and the client.  IMalloc is the generic interface to access that shared heap, CoTaskMemAlloc() and CoTaskMemFree() are the system provided helper functions to use that interface.

That said, this is *only* necessary in a case where the server allocates memory and the client has to release it.  Or the other way around.  Which should always be rare in an interop scenario, the odds for accidents are just too large.  In COM Automation there are just two such cases, a BSTR and a SAFEARRAY, types that are already wrapped.  You avoid it in other cases by having the method caller provide the memory and the callee fill it in.  Which also allows a strong optimization, the memory could come from the caller's stack.

Review the code and check who allocates the memory and who needs to release it.  If both exist in the same module then using new/malloc is fine because there's now a hard guarantee that the same CRT instance takes care of it.  If that's not the case then consider fixing it so the caller provides the memory and releases it.

Answer (score 4):

The allocation and freeing of memory must always come from the same source.  If you use `CoTaskMemAlloc` then you must use `CoTaskMemFree` to free the memory.

Note in C++ though the act of managing memory and object construction / destruction (`new / delete`) are independent actions.  It's possible to customize specific objects to use a different memory allocator and still allow for the standard `new / delete` syntax which is preferred.  For example

```
class MyClass { 
public:
  void* operator new(size_t size) {
    return ::CoTaskMemAlloc(size);
  }
  void* operator new[](size_t size) {
    return ::CoTaskMemAlloc(size);
  } 
  void operator delete(void* pMemory) {
    ::CoTaskMemFree(pMemory);
  }
  void operator delete[](void* pMemory) {
    ::CoTaskMemFree(pMemory);
  }   
};
```

Now I can use this type just like any other C++ type and yet the memory will come from the COM heap

```
// Normal object construction but memory comes from CoTaskMemAlloc
MyClass *pClass = new MyClass();
...  
// Normal object destruction and memory freed from CoTaskMemFree
delete pClass;
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the question is: Yes, you should use CoTaskMemFree to free memory allocated with CoTaskMemAlloc.

The other answers do a good job explaining why CoTaskMemAlloc and CoTaskMemFree are necessary for memory passed between COM servers and COM clients, but they didn't directly answer your question.

Your teacher was right: You should always use the corresponding release function for any resource.  If you use new, use delete.  If you use malloc, use free.  If you use CreateFile, use CloseHandle.  Etc.

Better yet, in C++, use RAII objects that allocate the resource in the constructor and release the resource in the destructor, and then use those RAII wrappers instead of the bare functions.  This makes it easier and cleaner to write code that doesn't leak, even if you get something like an exception.

The standard template library provides containers that implement RAII, which is why you should learn to use a std::vector or std::string rather than allocating bare memory and trying to manage it yourself.  There are also smart pointers like std::shared_ptr and std::unique_ptr that can be used to make sure the right release call is always made at the right time.

ATL provides some classes like ATL::CComPtr which are wrapper objects that handle the reference counting of COM objects for you.  They are not foolproof to use correctly, and, in fact, have a few more gotchas than most of the modern STL classes, so read the documentation carefully.  When used correctly, it's relatively easy to make sure the AddRef and Release calls all match up.

Comment: Using smart pointers is very important in COM (and in C++). The chance you make errors with reference counting is very high. Use CComPtr for objects created; use CComHeapPtr when COM api's return memory to be freed with CoTaskMemFree (e.g. StringFromCLSID).